# ReactiveUI: Scheudle task on UI thread from background thread

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I need to process a large data set on a background thread, then display that data in DataGrid controls in a WPF interface. The data comes in from an external, industrial device, for which I'm provided a third-party library. So, I get the data in a delegate from that library.

My problem is that I seem unable to schedule an operation on the MainUI thread from the background thread, and I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

The data view model:

```cs
    public class DataViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        public SourceList<SummaryData> SummaryData = new SourceList<SummaryData>();
        public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<SummaryData> SummaryDataView;


        public SourceList<EnergyTable> SampleData = new SourceList<EnergyTable>();
        public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<EnergyTable> SampleDataView;


        public DataViewModel()
        {
            SummaryData.Connect()
                .Bind(out SummaryDataView)
                .Subscribe();

            SampleData.Connect()
                .Bind(out SampleDataView)
                .Subscribe();

        }

    }
```

The third-party library delegate sends data.

```cs
        protected void OnSqlCommandCode(Tag tag)
        {
            // Process the 

            Observable.Start(
                 () => HandleData(),
                 RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
                 .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);
        }
```

The data gets processed...

```cs
    public void HandleData()
    {

        ImpactorResultData result;

        ... Processing ...

        // NOW I TRY TO UPDATE THE COLLECTIONS FROM THE MAIN UI THREAD
         Observable.Start(
            () => UpdateUiThreadCollections(result),
            RxApp.MainThreadScheduler
         );       
    }
```

I update the instance of DataViewModel. I expect, since I scheduled the operation to be performed on the UI Thread (above), that everything will go well. Instead, I get an exception that collections tied to the DataGrid must be updated in the main UI thread.

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Collections tied to data linked to a UI control need to be called from the 
        /// UI thread.
        /// 
        /// The other option is to remake the ObservableRangeCollection every time
        /// from the list. 
        /// </summary>
        protected static void UpdateUiThreadCollections(
            ImpactorResultData result
        )
        {
            dataViewModel.SummaryData.Add(result.SummaryData);

            dataViewModel.SampleData.Edit(innerList =>
            {
               innerList.Clear();
               innerList.AddRange(result.Samples);
           });

        }
```

For some reason, both:

```
         Observable.Start(
            () => UpdateUiThreadCollections(result),
            RxApp.MainThreadScheduler
         );     

          RxApp.MainThreadScheduler.Schedule(() =>
          {
              UpdateUiThreadCollections(result);
          });
```

still schedule the operation on the background thread. There must be something I'm not understanding about ReactiveUI or the Reactive Extensions.

Thank you in advance for any insights.

Comment: With calls like `Observable.Start(() => UpdateUiThreadCollections(result), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)` the observable doesn't actually start until you call `.Subscribe`. How are you subscribing to these observables?

Comment: ```Observable.Start( () => UpdateUiThreadCollections(result), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler); ``` has been calling the function without fail, no need for subscribe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to update your `SourceList` from a background thread.  You shouldn't need all that complicated logic.  Instead, use `System.Reactive.Linq` and the `ObserveOn()` extension just before you do your binding to a property that your UI actually uses.

In your viewmodel:

```
            SummaryData.Connect()
                .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .Bind(out SummaryDataView)
                .Subscribe();

            SampleData.Connect()
                .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .Bind(out SampleDataView)
                .Subscribe();
```

Oh, and I'm not a Wpf user, but I remember there being some extra ReactiveUI packages specifically for Wpf.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is right. See my comment on the question for more detail.

Comment: This was my original approach, and it didn't work. It still tried to update the collection from the background thread.

Comment: Just to make sure, you have installed the ReactiveUI.Wpf package in addition to the regular ReactiveUI package?  Because the Wpf package redefines the RxApp.MainThreadScheduler property to something other than the default.

Comment: This is the correct answer and the standard approach for marshalling the updates on the UI thread.

Comment: Lee -- There is a main project, which is a .NET Framework/WPF project. The Data Model firing the event, however, is in another project, which is .NET Standard 2.0. Does that mean I've created two MainThreadSchedulers?